# Remove null values from list and created using checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var html = '';
$('.bob').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
    if($("input[data-var='"+item+"']").length == 0)  
        $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="testclss"  data-var="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

I need to remove the null values and none values from the list

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz=""></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
 <div class="bob" data-xyz=""></div>
 <div class="bob" data-xyz="none"></div> 

<div class="checkboxes"></div>
```

Everything just works fine but i need to remove none and "" values from the list

Comment: Hm... have you tried to add `if (item)` before adding new checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter in the selector like this :

```
var html = '';
$('.bob[data-xyz!=""][data-xyz!="none"]').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).data('xyz');
    if($("input[data-var='"+item+"']").length == 0)  
        $('.checkboxes').append('<label><input class="testclss"  data-var="' + item + '" type="checkbox" />' + item + '</label>');
});
```

Comment: thanks  its working fine... is there any possibility of removing none

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looping through this list of `<div>`s looking for the blank data elements.  In this case, your if statement within the `.each()` loop should look something like this:

```
if ( $(this).data("xyz").length == 0 )
```